# Render envelope instead of error bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

The R snippet below plots my data perfectly with a logarithmic fit and error bars for the standard deviation from my data source.

I would like to change the error bars to use an envelope like I get with geom_smooth.

However, I can't get geom_smooth to accept ymin/ymax from my data. It always auto-calculates the envelope using other algorithms, which is not what I want. I've tried a dozen options with geom_smooth and stat_smooth and I can't figure out how to render an envelope with specific min/max values from my data set.

```
library(ggplot2)

temperature <- c(19.89, 19.46, 19.35, 19.16, 19.13, 19.14, 19.02, 19.07, 19.03, 19.03, 19.09, 19.00, 18.98, 19.02, 18.96, 18.81, 18.68, 18.60, 18.89, 18.84)
temperature_stddev <- c(0.045, 0.595, 1.035, 1.370, 1.610, 1.775, 1.915, 2.030, 2.125, 2.200, 2.255, 2.330, 2.360, 2.445, 2.455, 2.520, 2.915, 2.810, 2.750, 2.680)
data <- data.frame(time=(1:length(temperature)),temperature=temperature,temperature_stddev=temperature_stddev)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=temperature), fill="green") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=temperature-temperature_stddev, ymax=temperature+temperature_stddev), colour="black", width=.1) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~log(x),fill="red")
```

Comment: You're looking for `geom_ribbon`.

Comment: wow, that worked. I spent hours looking through galleries and docs and samples. thanks!